# Retrofit multiple callbacks one fragment

Tags: android, retrofit

```
class userfragment extends fragmentimplements Callback<ArrayList<Users>> , Callback<ArrayList<Countries>>
```

The idea behind id, in this fragment i have 2 url calls. One will return to me list of users, the other list of countries.How can I implement it? i am getting duplicate class retrofit2.callback.

Comment: You can do something like [this](http://ideone.com/97O8SI) ... But obviously checking type is annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make 2 different callback objects or you can make your custom interface which contains one additional parameter(say it ID) on basis of id you can do your work.